# Portenta H7 Baremetal Development and a Little Guidance on Embedded System Learning Roadmap

Tags: arduino, arm, embedded, bare-metal

I have just started in the field of Embedded System Firmware Development, and I was working on a project with Portenta H7, I really find it overwhelming sometimes.
I want to learn baremetal development, for example I was searching for timers [although i have very few idea about these terms watchdog, interrupts, timer , ISR] I was trying to implement a simple baremetal timer .
Then I found this forum where some one just implemented a timer using the regs directly , with least abstraction.
[this "Thread"](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/portenta-m7-timer-interrupt-example/696368/6)

Please guide me with some steps/resources , to learn more about ARM , MCU/MPU Architecture , and Firmware Development also how can I begin with Portenta H7 , as i found out STMCube IDE Doesnt supports the Portenta H7 board directly , and also the bootloader is different.

i have searched for some yt channels and books till now and I starting from there.

I just want a roadmap nothing else, stages, topics etc to cover

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions, not for open-ended discussions and advice. Your question will probably be closed.